# El tipo "undefined" no se puede asignar al tipo 'number'

Tags: angular

He intentado varias respuestas que aparecen en otras preguntas pero sigo sin poder resolver el problema, espero me puedan ayudar!

En el ts tengo esta variable:
public porcentaje = 0;

Y lo que quiero hacer es que se cargue una barra para subir un archivo, esta genera un link para descargar dicho archivo. El error está en la palabra porcentaje en el Math. Round

//Cambia el porcentaje

```
tarea.percentageChanges().subscribe((porcentaje) =>
  this.porcentaje = Math.round(**porcentaje**);
  if   (this.porcentaje == 100) {
    this.finalizado = true;
```

Comment: ¿Has verificado que el valor de porcentaje no sea `undefined`?

Comment: Donde puedo ver eso?

Comment: Imprime el valor de porcentaje. `console.log(porcentaje)`

Comment: Podrías por favor añadir a la pregunta el método `tarea.percentageChanges()`?

Comment: Puedes comprobar si es undefined con `if(porcentaje === undefined)`

Comment: Hola! Al imprimir el porcentaje sale en 0, porque tengo que comentar la parte del Math.round (porcentaje), entonces parece que no hace el avance. Al igualarla me marca más errores de los que hay :( Y con el ? no hay ningún cambio. Espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias!

Comment: podes mostrar el metodo `percentageChanges()`

Answer (score 1):

Cambia tu asignación a

```
this.porcentaje = Math.round(porcentaje ? porcentaje : 0);
```

Con eso evitas cualquier undefined o null, o cualquier falsy